# Ignoring all default arguments python / parse_args

Tags: python, argparse

All arguments to a python script are unknown. I am using this to parse them:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parsed, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()   
    for arg in unknown:
        if arg.startswith(("-")):
            parser.add_argument(arg.split(' ')[0])

    args = parser.parse_args()  
    ids = {}
    names = {}
    for arg in vars(args):
        priv = getattr(args, arg)
        name = arg[0:7]
        ids[arg] = priv
        names[arg] = name
```

This works until an argument starts with "-h" which is interpreted as a known (?) or default (?) argument and the script breaks with

`error: argument -h/--help: ignored explicit argument ...`

How can I disable this to only use unknown arguments?

Comment: If you don't define any arguments, why use `parse_known_args` instead of using `sys.argv` directly?

Comment: You can disable the `--help` option by passing `add_help=False` to the call to `ArgumentParser`.

Comment: @chepner perfect, thank you!